# Struts 2: Persisting a List with Model objects

Tags: html, forms, struts2, struts

I have a jsp page with a form and want to capture the data into a List so that I can display all the objects added later.

The iterator on my jsp page

```
 <s:iterator value="model" status="rowStatus">
    <tr>
        <td><s:textfield name="model[%{#rowStatus.index}].firstName" value="%{#firstName" /></td>
        <td><s:textfield name="model[%{#rowStatus.index}].lastName" value="%{model[#rowStatus.index].lastName}" /></td>
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

my action class

```
    public class StudentAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven, Preparable {

    private static List<Student> students;
    private Student student;

    public List<Student> getModel() {
        return students;
    }

    @Override
    public void prepare() {
        students = new ArrayList<>();
        student = new Student();
        student.setFirstName(firstName);
        student.setLastName(lastName);
        students.add(student);
    }

    public ArrayList<Payment> getBankList() {
        return payments;
    }

    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }
}
```

I'm new to Struts2 framework and this is confusing me so much. Are the values set incorrectly?? Any tips to how to list all the objects?

Comment: not clear what you are asking...

Comment: do you want to submit the form and receive the list back again at the action ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<s:textfield name="model[%{#rowStatus.index}].firstName"
```

The field name is wrong, you have getters & setters for `private static List<Student> students;`

and hence, the name of the field should be `students` as :

```
<s:iterator value="model" status="rowStatus">
    <tr>
        <td><s:textfield name="students[%{#rowStatus.index}].firstName" value="%{firstName}" /></td>
        <td><s:textfield name="students[%{#rowStatus.index}].lastName" value="%{lastName}" /></td>
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: he is implementing ModelDriven. getModel() will return List<Student>

Comment: that's why I kept the iterator value to be `model`. Although I agree, it's un-clear on what exactly is being required.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are missing the SETTER for `List<Student>`;
2. Use `prepare()` to prepare data for the page (eg. static `<select/>` values), not to set business data received from the page;
3. When manipulating attributes from the page in `prepare();`, you must use [paramsPrepareParamsStack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19495332/1654265) to access them;

And finally, but this is opinion based, avoid using ModelDriven... that feature is not really useful IMHO, and can mess up the things quickly, especially if you don't know what is going on;