# How to map URL like "/user/{user_id}" to a specific action?

Tags: java, regex, struts2, wildcard, wildcard-mapping

How could I map a regex number class `(\d)` to an action?

**Example:**

```
/user/123 , /user/345,  /user/546456 ....
```

Comment: You have to use a convention or rest plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Advanced Wildcards](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/wildcard-mappings.html#WildcardMappings-AdvancedWildcards):

> **Advanced Wildcards**
>
> From 2.1.9+ regular expressions can be defined defined in the action
>   name. To use this form of wild card, the following constants must be
>   set:
>
> ```xml
> <constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/> 
> <constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>
> <constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="regex" />
> ```
>
> The regular expressions can be in two forms, the simplest one is
>   `{FIELD_NAME}`, in which case the field with the `FIELD_NAME` in the
>   action will be populated with the matched text, for example:
>
> ```xml
> <package name="books" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
>     <action name="/{type}/content/{title}" class="example.BookAction">
>         <result>/books/content.jsp</result>
>     </action> 
> </package>
> ```
>
> In this example, if the url `/fiction/content/Frankenstein` is
>   requested, BookAction's field "`type`" will be set to "`fiction`", and the
>   field "`title`" will be set to "`Frankenstein`".

Note that if you need those parameters in `prepare()` method, [you need a tuned up Interceptor Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19495334/1654265).